# Get information on failure of pods relevant to replication controller

Tags: kubernetes

Is there a way to get the status of a deployment? The concept of deployment is modeled somehow? I can't find a "global" info on failures for pods relevant to a particular  and I don't know if looking for all the pods makes sense...
As "failure" I mean, for example, if I misspell the docker URL of the image... of course, I could just query one pod at random... but I'm not sure it would be the best idea to spot problems that are "common" to the whole deployment. 
What do you think? What is your proposed approach in this scenario?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this at the moment is using

```
kubectl describe rc <RC_NAME>
```

There's a proposal for implementing a deployment resource to cope with this use case: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/55b7500b33553a77f8dceb5404d6af1767399386/docs/proposals/deployment.md